# How to match a cell and (data on the same row) to a cell in a different column with the same value

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I hope someone can help me.

I have a column of reference numbers, over 23000 of them.

I also have a data set and it also contains the same reference numbers but not as many.

Is there a way to somehow match the reference numbers and the corresponding data to the reference number in the different column with the same value? As there are less values in the data set id like the reference numbers with no data to be blank.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Sure, there's a way. Have you tried anything yourself? Let us know what you tried, so we can help you correct it.

Comment: have a look at VLOOKUP, MATCH and INDEX functions

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentioned the best solution to this is likely to be non VBA.

Use a lookup function (I would recomoned match). The use a filter to find the values not in the secondary list.

If this needs to be done programaticly for whatever reason I find the simpelest way is to use a dictionary object. This allows you to use the exists method and build a correction of the subset of keys you want.

Best of luck.